# Is there a way to reduce mosquito bites from swelling

Tags: camping, mosquitoes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are some effective ways of reducing itching from a mosquito bite?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/629/what-are-some-effective-ways-of-reducing-itching-from-a-mosquito-bite)

Anyone have suggestions on how to reduce or prevent mosquito bites from swelling or becoming inflamed?

Typically when myself or my son gets a bite in most cases it will swell to the size of a silver dollar.  Aside from normal prevention techniques any tips on treatment or ways of reducing/preventing the swelling.

Notes:

- it itches but is not painful
- the swelling does go down on it's own after time but can last quite a while

Comment: Related: [What are some ways to reduce itching from mosquito bites?](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/629/what-is-the-most-effective-way-to-reduce-itching-from-mosquito-bites)

Comment: I would say they're duplicates - swelling and itching are caused by the same problem, and would be treated in much the same way.

Comment: I would disagree, b/c in my case ,and in many others, what may help itching does absolutely nothing for the swelling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible your son is [allergic to mosquitos](http://allergies.about.com/od/insectallergies/a/mosquitoallergy.htm).

Some natural solutions to itching & swelling include rubbing the area with:

- apple vinegar
- lemon juice
- eucalyptus oil
- Vicks vapor rub
- raw garlic
- raw honey reduces pain
- vinegar mixed with olive oil

You can also rub 1 tablespoon of lavender oil with 1 tablespoon of olive oil and rub it directly on the bite, this helps with reducing the swelling.  Keep this mixture away from the eyes though.

Source: [Natural Remedies for Insect Bites](http://www.toptipspot.com/tips/outdoors/howto/treat-insect-bites.php).

Have a look at [**AfterBite**](http://www.tendercorp.com/products.php?category=INSECT%20BITE%20TREATMENTS&cat=58), it is a treatment for insect bites and stings.

You can apply it to bitten areas, provides relief from mosquito, ticks, fleas, horse flies, black flies, etc.

<sub>Note: I am *not* affiliated with this product in any way, shape, or form.</sub>

Comment: Thank you @studiohack.  I am also allergic to them.  We do find that AfterBite is useful for taking away some of the itchiness however not so much on taking away the swelling side.